# Aligning a box, at the bottom instead of the top

Tags: html, css

Im looking for a way to order/align divs to the bottom instead of the top, for an example if you try to remove some of these divs with the class="box" in this fiddle

Currently code:

```
#holder {
    height: 220px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.box {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

It will remove the div from the bottom, I would like to reverse this behavior so it removes from the top instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/79L7Lud7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page elements flow from top to bottom, left to right.

To manipulate this, you essentially need to take the elements out of the normal flow, and position: absolute is one of the easier ways to do this.

For example:

```
#holder {position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
```

The only thing extra you'd need with this approach is an outer holder to reserve the page space.

http://jsfiddle.net/79L7Lud7/4/

Answer (score 1):

Generally elements align to the top of other elements. The best way to align to the bottom is to treat the 'holding' element as you have called it, as a table and then you can align elements to the bottom.

```
#holder {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;

    height: 220px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
```

}

Please see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/79L7Lud7/3/.

This will not work in IE7. For IE7 support you might want to think about absolute positioning.

https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

http://jsfiddle.net/79L7Lud7/3/